# Dynamics CRM Plugin - Refresh rollup on delete

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, rollup

I have a specific situation that I need to handle. I have a plugin that refreshes specific rollup field on invoice when invoice detail is created or updated.
Now I need to refresh that field when invoice detail is deleted.

---

Analyzing this problem, I realized that I cannot refresh rollup field on pre operation because the invoice detail record is not deleted yet, and on post operation I cannot retrieve invoice Guid from that particular record because it is gone.

Here the piece of code that handles rollup refresh on create/update:

```
Entity invoiceDetail = service.Retrieve("invoicedetail", targetId, new ColumnSet(true));
Guid invoiceID = ((EntityReference)invoiceDetail["invoiceid"]).Id;
if (targetEntity.Attributes.Contains("extendedamount"))
{
    Entity myEntity = service.Retrieve("invoice", invoiceID, new ColumnSet(true));
    CalculateRollupFieldRequest rollupRequest = new CalculateRollupFieldRequest
    {
        Target = new EntityReference("invoice", invoiceID),
        FieldName = "detailamount"
    };
    CalculateRollupFieldResponse response = (CalculateRollupFieldResponse)service.Execute(rollupRequest);
    myEntity = response.Entity;
    service.Update(myEntity);
}
```

Do you have any suggestions? I am going mad over this and can't think of anything...

Comment: What version of CRM are you using?

Comment: I am using CRM 2016

Comment: bocasa I wonder why you can't use the pre-event, the record will be deleted after this and if the record fails on the delete operation it will roll back.

Comment: It is because I want to refresh a value in Rollup field on invoice that is calculated from data on invoicedetail I want to delete. So if I do this on pre-operation, I will refresh the value and it will remain the same because the invoicedetail hasn't been deleted yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get guid on pre-event, and pass it to post-event - [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328579.aspx)

> sample code from MSDN:
>
> ```
> using System;
>
> // Microsoft Dynamics CRM namespace(s)
> using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
>
> namespace Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Samples
> {
>     /// <summary>
>     /// A plug-in that sends data to another plug-in through the SharedVariables
>     /// property of IPluginExecutionContext.
>     /// </summary>
>     /// <remarks>Register the PreEventPlugin for a pre-operation stage and the 
>     /// PostEventPlugin plug-in on a post-operation stage.
>     /// </remarks>
>     public class PreEventPlugin : IPlugin
>     {
>         public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
>         {
>             // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
>             Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext context = (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext)
>                 serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext));
>
>             // Create or retrieve some data that will be needed by the post event
>             // plug-in. You could run a query, create an entity, or perform a calculation.
>             //In this sample, the data to be passed to the post plug-in is
>             // represented by a GUID.
>             Guid contact = new Guid("{74882D5C-381A-4863-A5B9-B8604615C2D0}");
>
>             // Pass the data to the post event plug-in in an execution context shared
>             // variable named PrimaryContact.
>             context.SharedVariables.Add("PrimaryContact", (Object)contact.ToString());
>         }
>     }
>
>     public class PostEventPlugin : IPlugin
>     {
>         public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
>         {
>             // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
>             Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext context = (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext)
>                 serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext));
>
>             // Obtain the contact from the execution context shared variables.
>             if (context.SharedVariables.Contains("PrimaryContact"))
>             {
>                 Guid contact =
>                     new Guid((string)context.SharedVariables["PrimaryContact"]);
>
>                 // Do something with the contact.
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Nice one brate! Implementing this at the moment, will let you know how it goes...